# Dplyr: Viewing 2-Variable Summarise Output as a 2 x 2 Matrix

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dplyr group_by and summarise function combination working as expected, e.g...

```
output = M %>% group_by(alpha_start, alpha_end) %>% summarize(N=n())
```

...gives the following result:

```
A  X   1
A  Y   2
A  Z   3
B  Y   4
B  Z   5
C  X   6
C  Z   7
```

What is the most efficient way to produce an output that is a 2 x 2 matrix, complete with column and row labels...

```
   X  Y  Z
A  1  2  3
B  0  4  5
C  6  0  7
```

...instead of a set of rows with unique two-part keys?

Also, with the data I am using, there will always be many "missing" rows that need to be zero-filled in the 2x2 representation, so a direct reshaping of the output is not possible.

Comment: June 22 at 13:55 is the answer I would like to accept.  However, the third comment below that answer explains why it is incomplete for the version of R/tidyr/dplyr that I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot the data using `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```r
dat
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  A  X  1
# 2  A  Y  2
# 3  A  Z  3
# 4  B  Y  4
# 5  B  Z  5
# 6  C  X  6
# 7  C  Z  7

tidyr::pivot_wider(dat, V1, names_from = "V2", values_from = "V3", values_fill = 0)
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   V1        X     Y     Z
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 A         1     2     3
# 2 B         0     4     5
# 3 C         6     0     7
```

---

Note: `?tidyr` in tidyr-1.1.0 reports that

```
values_fill: Optionally, a (scalar) value that specifies what each
          'value' should be filled in with when missing.
```

but some time since they added to that ([here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html)):

```
values_fill     

Optionally, a (scalar) value that specifies what each value should be filled in with when missing. This can be a named list if you want to apply different aggregations to different value columns.
```

With the sample data provided, this is not necessary. However, if your real data is more complex (and has other non-integer fields that need filling), then you will need to change it to

```r
pivot_wider(..., values_fill = list(V3 = 0L))
```

Comment: Tried a direct implementation of this; getting a "subscript out of bounds" error.  (Also, is V1 a column-name that should be in quotes?)

Comment: This works as is with the data that you provided. `V1` can be quoted or not, the tidyr verbs tend to be able to use NSE as well. (For that matter, `V2` and `V3` do not need to be quoted, but I have old habits.)

Comment: OK -- got it to work, but the last argument has to be a list, i.e. `values_fill = list (V3=0)`

Comment: Odd. It works on tidyr-1.1.0 with this data. Perhaps it's something unique with your data. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2):

We may use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(n ~ alpha_start + alpha_end, output)
 alpha_end
alpha_start X Y Z
          A 1 2 3
          B 0 4 5
          C 6 0 7
```

#### data

```
output <- structure(list(alpha_start = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"C"), alpha_end = c("X", "Y", "Z", "Y", "Z", "X", "Z"), n = 1:7), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the [`xtabs` approach by @akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087481/12158757) is the simplest way to give the desired output. Here is an `igraph` solution

```
graph_from_data_frame(output) %>%
    set_vertex_attr(name = "type", value = names(V(.)) %in% output$alpha_end) %>%
    as_incidence_matrix(attr = "n")
```

which gives

```
  X Y Z
A 1 2 3
B 0 4 5
C 6 0 7
```